# Sails.js find where error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

everyone !

I'm working on sails with postgres. I've got a Playlist with a collection of tracks. like that :

```
Playlist = {
 tracks: {
  collection: track
 }
}
```

I try to make a request like that :

```
Playlist.find({tracks: 1}).exec(...)
```

To get all playlists which have the track id 1 !

But sails return => Details:  error: column playlist.tracks does not exist.

Don't understand because waterline created a table called "playlist_tracks__track_tracks_track" and the are all the relation.

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all playlists that contain a certain trackId you should pull the associated playlist based on the track. Then using map you can return just the playlist portion.

```
Tracks.findOne(1).populate('playlist').exec( (track) => {
  playlists = result.playlist
  console.log(playlists)
})
```

--- or ---

```
Playlists.find().populate('track', {id: 1}).exec( /*...*/ )
```

Comment: That is when we have a many to many association right ? Because I only have -> Playlist has_many tracks.

Comment: Ya, it will work with Many to Many or One to Many. The important thing is that your select criteria is based on track, so find your track first populate your playlists based on that, then you can pluck out the playlists array. This does have the downside of select the same playlist multiple times . . . . I will update with a second method.